# Python. Не получается унаследоваться от стандартного класса библиотеки tkinter с помощью метода super

Tags: python, классы, tkinter, наследование, множественное-наследование

Собираю интерфейс будущей программы с помощью библиотеки `tkinter`. Пытаюсь создать специализированный класс кнопок (`ButtonNum`), которые бы наследовали свой интерфейс от стандартного класса `Button`. Так как `Button` тоже наследуется от других классов внутри библиотеки `tkinter`, я прописал в конструкторе создаваемого класса (`ButtonNum`) метод `super().__init__()`. Если я правильно понимаю назначение этого метода, то `super().__init__()` должен по цепочке вызвать конструкторы всех родительских для `Button` классов и перетащить из них нужные аргументы и методы в создаваемый мною `ButtonNum`. То есть на выходе  по идее должен получиться дочерний класс, который содержит в себе весь функционал `Button`, но этого не происходит, т.к. при создании экземпляра `ButtonNum`, я получаю ошибку *TypeError: `__init__` got an unexpected keyword argument `'bg'`*. `bg` - это характерный для родительского `Button` аргумент, но он в `ButtonNum`не наследуется (хотя если унаследоваться без создания конструктора: `Сlass ButtonNum(Button):`, то ошибки не возникает и все работает как должно). 
*Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему и объясните, что конкретно я не понимаю в механизме наследования (по возможности)*
**Полный код**:

```
from tkinter import *


class ButtonNum(Button):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    toolbar = Frame(root, relief=SUNKEN, borderwidth=2)
    toolbar.configure(bg='#d6d5e8')

    button_1 = ButtonNum(toolbar, bg='#b6b5c9', text='1', height=2, width=5)
    button_1.grid(column=1, row=1)

    toolbar.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создали метод `__init__`, принимающий только аргумент self, а потом пытаетесь передать в него другие аргументы - поэтому возникает ошибка. Нужно принять все аргументы (позиционные и именованные) и передать их в `__init__` родительского класса:

```
class ButtonNum(Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Боже, как все было просто... А я тыкался по модулям ткинтера, чтобы выудить оттуда названия нужных мне аргументов и вписать их потом в конструктор своего класса. Спасибо огромное за помощь